# dehydration, но дегидраТАция, authentication, но аутентиФИкация

Tags: заимствования

Может быть, кто-то в курсе, откуда берутся дополнительные слоги в заимствованиях? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала. Не стоит объединять эти случаи. Общим является только то, что они так или иначе связаны с глаголами или действиями, а хорошо известно, что глаголы редко заимствуются напрямую. А если и заимствуются, то не из английского.

С дегидратацией все более или менее понятно. Появление слова связано не с английским глаголом, а скорее всего - с интернациональным (латинским) понятием гидрат (чего-то там). А вот от него уже образовано дегидратация. Несколько путает существование похожего (и по внешнему виду и по значению) слова "дигидрат" с префиксом "ди" (это от слова dihydrat), но это никак не отменяет сказанное.

С аутентификацией сложнее. Здесь, видимо, надо признать наличие русского суффикса фик[ация] *(сравните: идентификация, мистификация)*. Этот суффикс обычно лепится как раз к таким корням, не имеющим собственного "короткого" слова для образования действия по глаголу.

А вообще по поводу самой ситуации. Очень часто технические словари приводят упрощенную этимологию, указывая первоисточником образ в языке-источнике, но опуская этап преобразования, обкатки слова в русском. В результате появляется ошибочное мнение о прямом заимствовании (иногда даже - кальке) слова в русский. Но, как правило, происходит иначе. Заимствуется напрямую один какой-то морф (редко - глагольный), после чего уже непосредственно в русском происходит наращение его суффиксами и аффиксами. Бывает и другое родственные, казалось бы, слова, например глагол и действие по нему, заимствуются их разных языков. В таком случае слова тоже могут иметь разный облик, наследуя его из разных языков источников.

Есть, правда, и два хорошо известных примера прямого заимствования, приведших к подобным различиям. Эрозия - эродировать, транскрипция - транскрибировать.

Comment: Кстати, дорогая администрация! Вот этот ответ вы, видимо, считаете удовлетворительным. Отсебятина, грубый ляп, непростительный даже для пятиклассника, – но зато донельзя развернутый. Вот только цитат нет с контекстами – это минус.

Comment: @Niemand с удовольствием ознакомлюсь с вашим мнением о "ляпе". Но при чем здесь администрация?!

Comment: @Niemand этот ответ не противоречит правилам, а следовательно допустим. Если у вас другое мнение по данному вопросу, оставьте свой ответ.

Comment: Самсебетоварищ @Niеmand, я уже устал повторять, что не рассматриваю ваши утверждения построенные на умышленном оскорблении коверканьем ника. Если вам так приспичило использовать слово "товарищ", то ник пишете без собаки. Иное просто глупо. "Собака" же и есть универсальное средство замены всех титулований на ресурсе.